# How can I attach a policy to a resource (in this case a PubSub topic)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name   = "argo-events"
}

resource "google_service_account" "argo_events_pubsub_publish" {
  account_id   = "pubsub-publish"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "argo_events_pubsub_publish" {
  role   = "roles/pubsub.editor"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.argo_events_pubsub_publish.email}"
}
```

This will create a service account with editor permissions on all PubSub infrastructure of the project.

How can I attach the policy (resulting from Service Account + roles/pubsub.editor) to the initially created topic?

(Such that the Service Account has permissions from roles/pubsub.editor but only on the initially created topic named "argo-events".)

---

The question was written under the assumption that terraform implements the policy attachment analogous to GCPs generic concept.

Comment: I don't know the google provider but if you want to reference attributes between resources you can do so using the `google_service_account.argo_events_pubsub_publish.account_id`. So providing the value you want is returned you just need to reference it in the related resource

Comment: true, but my question is more aimed at what terraform resource I have to use to make this work.

Comment: Use `google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding` or `google_pubsub_topic_iam_member`. This link has an example. Once you complete a solution post an answer. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_topic_iam#google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, will give it a try tomorrow. Didn't even consider checking for a PubSub-specific resource ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to attach a policy to a topic or a subscription. Interestingly the approach is not generic but specific to what resource you want to bind to (in this case a pubsub topic) and there are at least three ways how to do it:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_topic_iam
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_subscription_iam

In this case a solution could look like this:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "topic" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.argo_events_pubsub_publish.email}",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_policy" "policy" {
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.topic.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.topic.policy_data
}
```